# Отображения друзей с ФБ на ресурсе

Tags: facebook-api

После регистрации пользователя на ресурсе через Facebook нужно вытягивать и отображать всех его друзей.
Сейчас API Facebook не позволяет этого сделать. Возможно лишь отображать тех пользователей, которые зарегистрировались на нашем ресурсе. 
Нужно решить этот вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Помечаете ваш сайт/приложение как "игру", запрашиваете необходимые права у пользователя и можно получить список всех его друзей. См. подробнее [здесь](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/invitable_friends/).

Пометить "как игру" можно в настройках приложения, на вкладке "app-details", там выбираете категорию "Games", только тогда можно будет получить список друзей (если пользователь предоставил соответствующие права).

Как вариант - пишите на FB и просите сделать для вас исключение (только надо быть готовым к тому, что на вашу просьбу забьют)